# Wildfly 11 web admin - cannot connect remotely with Firefox or Chrome, only with Microsoft Edge

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, wildfly, wildfly-11

**[SOLVED]** I installed Wildfly 11 on my Debian (Stretch) server and started it as service. I could connect remotely to web admin only with Microsoft Edge but Firefox refuses to log in. It ask for username/password but don't let in...

Some details:

For starting service I used the default scripts, config files in ${wildfly_root}/docs/contrib/scripts/systemd as it was desribed in README.
Added ManagementRealm user with ./add-user.sh
Started and enabled the service, it runs perfectly.

From my Windows machine (Win10 pro64) I could log in to web admin with Edge but Firefox (*and* Chrome) refuses to let me in with the same login/password. Firefox is important because I want access remotely from another Linux machine...

What can cause this weird behaviour?
I'd appriciate your ideas/help! Thanks in advance!
The config and service files are below.

**[SOLUTION]**: use only digits, symbols, and **english** characters.
The root of problem were the Hungarian characters in password.

Launch.sh at ${wildfly_root}/bin

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "x$WILDFLY_HOME" = "x" ]; then
   WILDFLY_HOME="/srv/wildfly"
fi
if [[ "$1" == "domain" ]]; then
   $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/domain.sh -c $2 -b $3 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0
else
   $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/standalone.sh -c $2 -b $3 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0
fi
```

wildfly.conf at /etc/wildfly

```
# The configuration you want to run
WILDFLY_CONFIG=standalone.xml
# The mode you want to run
WILDFLY_MODE=standalone
# The address to bind to
WILDFLY_BIND=0.0.0.0
```

wildfly.service at /etc/systemd/system

```
[Unit]
Description=The WildFly Application Server
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=httpd.service

[Service]
Environment=LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf
User=wildfly
LimitNOFILE=102642
PIDFile=/var/run/wildfly/wildfly.pid
ExecStart=/srv/wildfly/bin/launch.sh $WILDFLY_MODE $WILDFLY_CONFIG $WILDFLY_BIND
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

standalone.xml at ${wildfly_root}/standalone/configuration

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:5.0">
    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
.../extension modules/...
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.security.manager"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
    </extensions>
    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
               .../Application Realm stuff/...
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            ...
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:2.0">
            <default-job-repository name="in-memory"/>
            <default-thread-pool name="batch"/>
            <job-repository name="in-memory">
                <in-memory/>
            </job-repository>
            <thread-pool name="batch">
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:bean-validation:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:core-management:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
            <datasources>
                .../datasource stuff/...
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <concurrent>
                <context-services>
                    <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                </context-services>
                <managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                </managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                </managed-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
            </concurrent>
            <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:5.0">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-worker-pools" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-cpu-count" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple"/>
                <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                <data-stores>
                    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </data-stores>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default">
                <channel-creation-options>
                    <option name="READ_TIMEOUT" value="${prop.remoting-connector.read.timeout:20}" type="xnio"/>
                    <option name="MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES" value="1234" type="remoting"/>
                </channel-creation-options>
            </remote>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <default-security-domain value="other"/>
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
            <log-system-exceptions value="true"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:1.2" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
            <providers>
                <aggregate-providers name="combined-providers">
                    <providers name="elytron"/>
                    <providers name="openssl"/>
                </aggregate-providers>
                <provider-loader name="elytron" module="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/>
                <provider-loader name="openssl" module="org.wildfly.openssl"/>
            </providers>
            <audit-logging>
                <file-audit-log name="local-audit" path="audit.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" format="JSON"/>
            </audit-logging>
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="ApplicationDomain" default-realm="ApplicationRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="ApplicationRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                    <realm name="local"/>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="ManagementDomain" default-realm="ManagementRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="ManagementRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                    <realm name="local" role-mapper="super-user-mapper"/>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
            <security-realms>
                <identity-realm name="local" identity="$local"/>
                <properties-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                    <users-properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                    <groups-properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
                <properties-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                    <users-properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                    <groups-properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
            </security-realms>
            <mappers>
                <simple-permission-mapper name="default-permission-mapper" mapping-mode="first">
                    <permission-mapping>
                        <principal name="anonymous"/>
                        <permission class-name="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.BatchPermission" module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet" target-name="*"/>
                        <permission class-name="org.wildfly.transaction.client.RemoteTransactionPermission" module="org.wildfly.transaction.client"/>
                        <permission class-name="org.jboss.ejb.client.RemoteEJBPermission" module="org.jboss.ejb-client"/>
                    </permission-mapping>
                    <permission-mapping match-all="true">
                        <permission class-name="org.wildfly.security.auth.permission.LoginPermission"/>
                        <permission class-name="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.BatchPermission" module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet" target-name="*"/>
                        <permission class-name="org.wildfly.transaction.client.RemoteTransactionPermission" module="org.wildfly.transaction.client"/>
                        <permission class-name="org.jboss.ejb.client.RemoteEJBPermission" module="org.jboss.ejb-client"/>
                    </permission-mapping>
                </simple-permission-mapper>
                <constant-realm-mapper name="local" realm-name="local"/>
                <simple-role-decoder name="groups-to-roles" attribute="groups"/>
                <constant-role-mapper name="super-user-mapper">
                    <role name="SuperUser"/>
                </constant-role-mapper>
            </mappers>
            <http>
                <http-authentication-factory name="management-http-authentication" http-server-mechanism-factory="global" security-domain="ManagementDomain">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </http-authentication-factory>
                <http-authentication-factory name="application-http-authentication" http-server-mechanism-factory="global" security-domain="ApplicationDomain">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="BASIC">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="Application Realm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="FORM"/>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </http-authentication-factory>
                <provider-http-server-mechanism-factory name="global"/>
            </http>
            <sasl>
                <sasl-authentication-factory name="management-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ManagementDomain">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="JBOSS-LOCAL-USER" realm-mapper="local"/>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </sasl-authentication-factory>
                <sasl-authentication-factory name="application-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ApplicationDomain">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="JBOSS-LOCAL-USER" realm-mapper="local"/>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </sasl-authentication-factory>
                <configurable-sasl-server-factory name="configured" sasl-server-factory="elytron">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="wildfly.sasl.local-user.default-user" value="$local"/>
                    </properties>
                </configurable-sasl-server-factory>
                <mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory name="elytron" sasl-server-factory="global">
                    <filters>
                        <filter provider-name="WildFlyElytron"/>
                    </filters>
                </mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory>
                <provider-sasl-server-factory name="global"/>
            </sasl>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:2.0">
            <worker name="default"/>
            <buffer-pool name="default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">
           .../cache containter stuff/...
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:5.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:3.0">
            <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
            <remote-naming/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:4.0">
            <endpoint/>
            <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:request-controller:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0">
            <deployment-permissions>
                <maximum-set>
                    <permission class="java.security.AllPermission"/>
                </maximum-set>
            </deployment-permissions>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jaspitest" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication-jaspi>
                        <login-module-stack name="dummy">
                            <login-module code="Dummy" flag="optional"/>
                        </login-module-stack>
                        <auth-module code="Dummy"/>
                    </authentication-jaspi>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:4.0">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <object-store path="tx-object-store" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/11"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:4.0"/>
    </profile>
    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

Comment: What do the developer tools in Firefox and Chrome say - is there an error or other message?

Comment: @stdunbar, thank you for your idea. I checked the traffic and results. Inspecting it I realized that the password can consume only digits, some symbols and English alphabet letters and I used Hungarian letters as well... :) Changing password solved my problem! :)